# How to set a controls visibility to false at design time visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a few group boxes that stack over each each. In previous editions of visual studio I used to move the controls off screen, then set their positions when the form loaded.

This seems like an archaic method, is there a way to set a controls visibility to false at design time? So that it is not visible in the form designer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are having difficulty with, but there is a Visible property for every control I am aware of. To set at design time, you merely choose the control in question and then go through the properties until you find Visible and set it to false.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This property only reflects at run time. In the forms designer the control is still visible. This is usually not a problem, but when you have a fairly complex interface, and need to have overlapping controls it does become a problem.

Comment: I see, you want the control to be invisible in the designer, not invisible as far as design time setup of runtime behavior. Unfortunately, I know of no way to set a control to be invisible on the form itself. There are ways around the issue, however. If you set up the grouped elements on a separate control surface, you can still edit them, set up events, etc., even though they are overlapped and ugly on the design time surface. But this is a workaround and not a direct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a few years late, but have you tried `d:IsHidden="True"`?

This uses `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` (which is usually included automatically), and it makes the control invisible in the designer, but otherwise does not affect anything.